How to make this shape?

I want to achieve a custom tab bar shape in SwiftUI that looks like the image above. The top corners (top-left and top-right) should be rounded normally, and the bottom corners (bottom-left and bottom-right) should have an "inverted" curve, giving it a unique outward curve look.
I've tried using clipShape with a simple RoundedRectangle, but that doesn't allow for inward curves at the bottom corners. How can I create a custom SwiftUI shape that allows me to have standard rounded corners at the top and inverted (outward) curves at the bottom, similar to the shape in the image?
My Attempt:
//
//  CustomTabBar.swift
//  skill
//
//  Created by Chetan Patil on 06/12/24.
//

import SwiftUI

struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .favourites // State to track selected tab
    
    enum Tab {
        case favourites, accounts, payments, deposits
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            // Tabs Content
            
            
            // Custom Tab Bar
            HStack {
                tabItem(title: "Favourites", isSelected: selectedTab == .favourites) {
                    selectedTab = .favourites
                }
                
                tabItem(title: "Accounts", isSelected: selectedTab == .accounts) {
                    selectedTab = .accounts
                }
                tabItem(title: "Payments", isSelected: selectedTab == .payments) {
                    selectedTab = .payments
                }
                tabItem(title: "Deposits", isSelected: selectedTab == .deposits) {
                    selectedTab = .deposits
                }
            }
            .background(Color(red: 0/255, green: 64/255, blue: 143/255))
           
            // Blue background
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                FavouritesView()
                    .tag(Tab.favourites)
                AccountsView()
                    .tag(Tab.accounts)
                PaymentsView()
                    .tag(Tab.payments)
                DepositsView()
                    .tag(Tab.deposits)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 400)
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom) // Ignore safe area for the tab bar
    }

    // Tab Item View
    private func tabItem(title: String, isSelected: Bool, action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: isSelected ? .bold : .regular))
                .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .black : .gray)
                .padding(.vertical, 12)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .background(isSelected ? Color.white : Color.clear) // Highlight selected tab
        .clipShape(
            .rect(
                topLeadingRadius: 10,
                bottomLeadingRadius: -10,
                bottomTrailingRadius: -10,
                topTrailingRadius: 10
            )
        )
    }
}


// Example Content Views for Each Tab
struct FavouritesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Favourites View")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 400)
            .background(Color.white)
    }
}


struct AccountsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Accounts View")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 400)
            .background(Color.white)
    }
}

struct PaymentsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Payments View")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 400)
            .background(Color.white)
    }
}

struct DepositsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Deposits View")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 400)
            .background(Color.white)
    }
}


#Preview {
    CustomTabBar()
}


You can create your own shapes in SwiftUI. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes

This question is similar to: What are the tangent parameters found in the .addArc method for SwiftUI?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I would suggest using a custom Shape for this.

A simple way to add the rounded corners is to use the Path function addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:). Here you just pass in the points that would be at the corners if you were to use straight lines to draw the shape (in other words, a shape drawn with square corners instead of rounded corners).

You might want to let the sloping part go outside (beyond) the drawing area. Alternatively, you could stay within the drawing area, but then you will probably need to enlarge the area for the shape in some other way when you use it as background to the tab items.


struct TabShape: Shape {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 12
    let slopeWidth: CGFloat = 20

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
        let topLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
        let slopeBegin = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - (slopeWidth / 2), y: rect.minY)
        let slopeEnd = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX + (slopeWidth / 2), y: rect.maxY)
        let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX + (slopeWidth / 2) + cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY)
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: bottomLeft)
            path.addArc(tangent1End: topLeft, tangent2End: slopeBegin, radius: cornerRadius)
            path.addArc(tangent1End: slopeBegin, tangent2End: slopeEnd, radius: cornerRadius)
            path.addArc(tangent1End: slopeEnd, tangent2End: bottomRight, radius: cornerRadius)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}

Testing this shape in isolation:
TabShape()
    .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
    .border(.red)


To use it in your custom tab bar, just replace the background behind the tab items:
private func tabItem(title: String, isSelected: Bool, action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
    Button(action: action) {
        // ...as before
    }
    .background {
        TabShape()
            .fill(isSelected ? .white : .clear)
    }
}


To make space for the slope on the last tab, you probably want to add some padding to the HStack that contains the tab items:
// Custom Tab Bar
HStack {
    // ...as before
}
.padding(.trailing, 16) //  here
.background(Color(red: 0/255, green: 64/255, blue: 143/255))



Wow, this solution works perfectly! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it so clearly. Thanks again for your help!

@Chetanpatil You're welcome, thanks for accepting the answer

the solution worked perfectly

@Chetanpatil Btw, since you are using a custom tab bar, you probably want to hide the native tab bar. The native tab bar is still there, even though the tab items are empty - if you tap in the lower region of the main content area then you will find that the tab changes! See this answer for how to solve.

Excellent answer. (Voted). I didn't realize that the SwiftUI Path exposed the "gnarlier" functions from CGPath like addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:). (And it took me a lot of head-scratching to figure that function out. I would have killed for your clear, simple explanation.)

I'd argue it's easier to make it as an SVG in Illustrator and make a custom shape from it.

@DanielCrompton how would you convert an SVG into a Path/CGPath/UIBezierPath? I'm guessing that you could only convert it to an Image, which is more processor-intensive, memory-intensive, and offers a lot less functionality. (You can scale, transform, and animate Path objects at arbitrary resolution, with hardware-supported performance and without any loss. Not so with images.)

@DuncanC there's quite a few libraries to parse the path part of an SVG into a SwiftUI shape, and resources on how to use them.

I've never actually done it but read about it:

https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit
https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG
https://github.com/richardpiazza/SwiftSVG
https://medium.com/@ckinetandrii/you-can-convert-svg-to-swiftui-code-in-3-steps-6fd92b9ab017


@DanielCrompton grate catch :)
